# What is purpose of myBatis NStringTypeHandler?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, mybatis

We need to use NStringTypeHandler for persisting i18n strings into NVARCHAR fields of DB.

But I looked into source code and looks like it doesn't do anything.

```
public class NStringTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler {

public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, Object parameter, JdbcType jdbcType)
  throws SQLException {
     //    ps.setNString(i, ((String) parameter));
     ps.setString(i, ((String) parameter));
 }

 public Object getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName)
  throws SQLException {
     //    return rs.getNString(columnName);
     return rs.getString(columnName);
 }

 public Object getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex)
  throws SQLException {
     //    return cs.getNString(columnIndex);
     return cs.getString(columnIndex);
 }

 }
```

Maybe, I miised something. But set/get NString is commented in source code.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `NStringTypeHandler` looks wrong. (It's supposed to support National Character Set Type Data and it isn't).

Just for your info, there is a newer version of `NStringTypeHandler` in the trunk which this time uses generic version `BaseTypeHandler` as its base class. However, the uncommented lines were not removed and the `setNString` is not used there as well.

Unfortunately, there is also no history available explaining the uncommented lines. The file was [checked-in with the commented lines](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/source/diff?path=/mirror/ibatis/java/ibatis-3/tags/java_release_3.0.0-190/ibatis-3-core/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/type/NStringTypeHandler.java&format=side&r=1630&old_path=/mirror/ibatis/java/ibatis-3/tags/java_release_3.0.0-190/ibatis-3-core/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/type/NStringTypeHandler.java&old=).

My suggestion is to [submit an issue here](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/issues/entry) (to at least get that weird implementation explained).